# How can I compute the operator norm of convolution?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question on real analysis. For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, Define $\lambda_f(\xi)=f\ast \xi$ where $\xi\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$. In my book, it says that the operator norm $\|\lambda_f\|$ is $\|\widehat{f}\|_\infty$. I proved one direction $\|\lambda_f\|\leq\|\widehat{f}\|_\infty$, but cannot figure out how to prove the converse. Any suggestion?